# Combine these basic php functions

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to add these two php functions `<?php the_field('city'); ?>` and `<?php the_field('country'); ?>` into the function below in place of the `$city` and `$country` variables.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[forecast location="' . $city . ' , ' . $country. '" caption="" numdays="3" iconset="Cartoon" class="css_table_class" cache="true"]'); ?>
```

Would appreciate any help my PHP isn't very good at all and I keep getting erros.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`the_field` outputs the field value instead of returning it. You need `get_the_field`:

```
echo do_shortcode(
    '[forecast location="' . get_the_field('city') . ' , ' . get_the_field('country') . 
    '" caption="" numdays="3" iconset="Cartoon" class="css_table_class" cache="true"]'
);
```